# Where do I put Android Studio Components when I download them manually?

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

Where do I put Android Studio Components when I download  them manually?

For example:

[image]
If I click `download` in screenshot above,the speed  is very slow.So I try to download it with browser, it is fast.
url:    https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis_playstore/x86-28_r08.zip

**Question:**
Where do I put it after I download and extract it?
SDK path is `C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk`:
[image]

Comment: Believe it should go inside the system-images directory.  There are sub directories there.  I would question why it's slow downloading via Android Studio IDE though and i've not done this manually though so not sure if there is something else that is done under the hood when it installs that you need to also do!

Comment: Read this answer below and see if it solve your problem
[an answer on stackoverflow](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/102957)